# How to initialize class properties in inherited models

Tags: django

I have a very simple model:

```
class Base (models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Foo(Base):
    model = None
    Field = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    Field2 = models.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, context = None, *args, **kwargs):

        self.Field = "Test string"
        self.model = context
        self.WorkingField = "Another test string"
        self.price = 1000
        self.Field2 = 500
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I opened shell and tried to do some tests. I would like to initialize my class by calling constructor

```
t = Foo(Bar)
```

I expect that `t.Field` returns me a string value "Test string". Also I expect that `t.Field2` returns me  500 result.

Unexpectedly this property values are empty - the response in shell is an empty string ''.
I suppose this problem has something to do with these property declarations

```
Field = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

I already tried:

1. initialize a string property without declaration in class

```
class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self, context = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Field = "Test string"
```

Everything works OK. But I have to create a database field for this property, so I want to declare it in model

2. I try various combinations of super().**init**(). With params, without params. I tried to declare **init** method in the Base class of my model.
   Nothing helps.

How I can fix it?

Comment: You should *first* call the `super`, and then set the fields.

Comment: Oh, sure.
This is so obvious but I didn't pay ttention on it and vaste almost 3 hours trying to find reason
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` *before* setting the field values, since the `super()` will set default values, etc. For example:

```
class Foo(Base):
    Field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Field2 = models.IntegerField()
    model = None

    def __init__(self, context = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Field = 'Test string'
        self.model = context
        self.WorkingField = 'Another test string'
        self.price = 1000
        self.Field2 = 500
```

That being said, it is usually a *very bad* idea to overwrite the `__init__` function of a Django model, as is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/):

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the `__init__` method. If you do so, however, **take care not to change the calling signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being saved**.

Actually you do not need to provide initial values at all like that. If you want to add a default, you can simply specify one, like:

```
class Foo(Base):
    Field = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Test string')
    Field2 = models.IntegerField(default=500)

    # ...
```

or you can specify the values when you *construct* a `Foo` object, like:

```
Foo(Field='Test string', Field2=500)
```

> **Note**: the [**PEP-008**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines advice to use `CamelCase` for classes, and `lowercase_with_underscores` for class attributes. So you might want to rename <s>`Field`</s> and <s>`Field2`</s> to `field` and `field2`.